# Can someone help me understand this code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

[Here's the full project](http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_robot.html)

I don't understand how the graph[from] works, is it checking the value like in array at 'from' location? Or is 'from' a property name of the object? I tried both in my terminal, using from as property name works when it is a number. Using it as an array index gives me an error that 'from is undefined'.
Also the graph[from].push(to). How it works?

```
function buildGraph(edges) {
  let graph = Object.create(null);

  function addEdge(from, to) {
    if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
    } else {
      graph[from].push(to);
    }
  }
  for (let[from, to] of edges.map(r = > r.split("-"))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }
  return graph;
}
const roadGraph = buildGraph(roads);
```

Comment: `addEdge` is a function. Functions have parameters that you pass when you call them. `addEdge` is declared `function addEdge(from, to)` which means that when the function is invoked in the code, whatever the first parameter is that you pass into the function is `from`. For instance if you were to write `addEdge(1, 2)` - `from` inside the function `addEdge` is a variable housing `1`. So when you say `graph[from]` inside the `addEdge` function you could interpret it as `graph[1]`

Comment: I'm guessing if you passed `["blue-red", "green-blue"]` as `roads` you'd get an object like `{ blue: ["red", "green"], red: ["blue"], green: ["blue"] }`.

Comment: @karthick I know what addEdge does. I am just confused by the syntax of graph[from]. We created graph as a null Object. What does the 'from' represent in 'graph[from]' ?

Comment: `graph[from]` is the bracket notation for object property retrieval.

Comment: as @HereticMonkey said, if graph is an object, you can set key value pairs within graph by saying `graph["mykey"] = "myvalue"` - this is similar to saying `graph.mykey = "myvalue"` except that with the fomer you can utilize things like spaces since your key is a string. You access the value by pointing to  `graph["mykey"]` -  it's also worth noting that in your code the `[to]` is simply an array that has `to` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of roads, that are defined as list os String pairs, joined by '-', like `"Alice's House-Bob's House"` is a road connecting Alice and Bob house.

Each road is then combined of 2 edges: Alice House and Bob house (you split road to edge with `split('_')`).

Now you create a map of roads, here it's called `graph`. For each road you add 2 edged, from point A-> B and B-> A.

```
addEdge(from, to);
addEdge(to, from);
```

Because you can use same road to travel in both directions.

Each addEdge call checks if there is a edge `from` registered already in the graph.
But in my opinion it should look like this:

```
 function addEdge(from, to) {
    if (!graph[from]) { // if object 'from' is not yet register, add an empty array to from key
      graph[from] = [];
    }
    graph[from].push(to); // add edge 'to, to mapping of 'from'
  }
```

so in the end you will build a map, that would look like this:

```
graph = {
   'Alice house': ['Bob house', 'Post office'],
   'Post office': ['Alice house'],
   'Bob house': ['Alice house']
}
```

Comment: You could also do `graph[from] = [...graph[from] || [], to];` if you wanted :).

Comment: Very nice inline - I need to remember it:)

Comment: Thank you so much it helped. 
Also can you explain how does the ' graph[from].push(to)' works? 
I know push places an element at the end of array, but graph is not an array, how does it work here?

Comment: @MazharAli graph isn't an array, the key `from` inside `graph` points to an array. For instance `graph["Alice house"].push("Post office")` will push the value "Post office" to the array located at `graph["Alice house"]`

Answer (score 0):

Hit your favorite browser's dev tools. Type this in it :

```
let roadsX = [
  "Alice's House-Bob's House",   "Alice's House-Cabin",
  "Alice's House-Post Office",   "Bob's House-Town Hall",
  "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
  "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
  "Grete's House-Shop",          "Marketplace-Farm",
  "Marketplace-Post Office",     "Marketplace-Shop",
  "Marketplace-Town Hall",       "Shop-Town Hall"
];

function buildGraph(edges) {
  let graph = Object.create(null);
  function addEdge(from, to) {
    if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
    } else {
      graph[from].push(to);
    }
  }
  for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }
  return graph;
}

let roadGraphX = buildGraph(roads);

console.log(roadGraphX);
```

You'll see what the function does.

Comment: The OP asked for an *explanation* of what the code does, not what the code ends up doing.